# Using a StringTokenizer to replace 3 letter words with Asteriks?

Tags: java

Looking to replace all 3 letter words in a string with "*", so for example, if someone typed in "I forgot to ask", it would output "I forgot to ***", this is what I have, not sure where to go from here.

```
public static void main (String[] args)
{
    c = new Console ();


    c.print("Enter a string: ");
    String phrase;
    phrase = c.readLine();

    StringTokenizer phrase = new StringTokenizer (phrase);
    while (phrase.hasMoreTokens ())
    {
        c.print (phrase.nextToken());

    }



} // main method
```

Comment: Check `.length()` of word, if it is 3 print `***` else print word?

Comment: `String phrase = c.readLine().replaceAll("\\D{3}", "***");`

Comment: would I put that line under c.print?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch You probably meant `\S` instead of `\D`. Also it would be good to wrap this regex with `\b`, otherwise we would replace all 3 non-digit (or non-space) characters with `***` like `abcde` into `***de`.

Comment: @SoloTriesToLearn Printing is last step, before it you need to decide what you want to print. To make it possible store current token in variable. This will allow you to execute some methods on it (like `.length()` to get amount of characters) and then potentially pass this token to printing method.

Comment: @Pshemo New to this, looking through my notes, I can't find where I would store it is a variable? And then would Elliotts  String phrase = c.readLine().replaceAll("\\D{3}", "***"); not work in this situation?

Answer (score 0):

Interesting question. I solved your problem using Java 8 and I just added a simple test that proves that it works:

```
import org.junit.Test;
import static java.util.Arrays.asList;
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.joining;
import static org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert.assertThat;
import static org.hamcrest.core.Is.is;

public class SoloTriesToLearn {

    public String wordReplacer(String sentence) {

       return asList(sentence.split(" ")).stream()
               .map(word -> word.length() == 3  ? "***" : word + " ")
               .collect(joining());

    }

    @Test
    public void shouldReplaceWordsWithAsterisk() {
        String result = wordReplacer("I forgot to ask");
        assertThat(result, is("I forgot to ***"));
    }
}
```

So basically what I am doing is first split the words, then I stream them and I do a mapping that detects if the length is == 3 and then I return the ***. At the end of the stream I collect the elements back to a single String by joining.

I hope you find this code useful, I find the functional approach very easy for this kind of manipulations.

**Update**
Ok, so if your teacher doesn't understand Java8, don't worry here the naughty way using that Tokenizer you wanted ;)

```
import org.junit.Test;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;
import static org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert.assertThat;
import static org.hamcrest.core.Is.is;

public class SoloTriesToLearn {

    public String wordReplacer(String sentence) {

        StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(sentence);
        String acumulator = "";

            while (st.hasMoreElements()) {
                String currentWord = (String) st.nextElement();
                if(currentWord.length() == 3) {
                    acumulator += "***";
                } else {
                    acumulator += currentWord + " ";
                }
            }
        return acumulator;
    }

    @Test
    public void shouldReplaceWordsWithAsterisk() {
        String result = wordReplacer("I forgot to ask");
        assertThat(result, is("I forgot to ***"));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, this is for an online checkmark class that's supposed to help me learn Java, is there a way you know how to do this using a tokenizer?

Comment: @SoloTriesToLearn Ok, sure. Check the update. I just added you code to do it using that Tokenizer thing.

Comment: I tried running that code, and got 10 errors? The class is using the 'Ready to Program Java IDE' if that makes a difference? If it would be easier, I could show you the note we got? @sfrj

Comment: @SoloTriesToLearn The code compiles and runs well you are probably have no enough understanding how to run it. I think, the easiest for you, would be: 1- Take the body of the method wordReplacer(just the body) and paste it in your main method. 2- Into the StringTokenizer, just pass directly the sentence you want to transform. 3- Add a println that prints the acumulator, and remove the return. If you did it correctly, you should see the sentence printing in your terminal when you run your main method.

Answer (score 0):

Or just:

```
phrase = phrase.replaceAll("\\b[a-zA-Z]{3}\\b", "***");
```

Answer (score -1):

```
public static void main (String[] args)
{
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter a string: ");
    String phrase;
    phrase = input.nextLine();
    ArrayList<String> sentence = new ArrayList<>();

    StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(phrase);
    while (tokenizer.hasMoreTokens ())
    {
        sentence.add(tokenizer.nextToken());
    }
    for (String word : sentence)
    {
        if (word.length() == 3)
        {
            word = "***";
        }
        System.out.print(word + " ");
    }


} // main method
```